# ramdisk device creation failed due to insufficient memory. Status 0xc0000017. When i try to start windows server 2008 R2

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, windows-server-2008-r2

I have the following:-

- VMWare workstation version 9, with Windows Server 2008 R2 data center installed.
- I have installed Windows 2008 R2 inside the VM using an iso image.
- The host is Windows 7.

I use to work well with the VM, but after adding a new VM to the same workstation . I start getting the following error when starting my old VM

> Ramdisk device creation failed due to insufficient memory.

And on the windows boot manger screen they mentioned to :-

- Insert my windows installation disc and restart my PC.
- click “repair your computer”

but I am not sure if this will fix the problem, baring in mind that the RAM assigned to the VM  is 24 GB and 80 GB hard disk.

[image]

So can anyone offer some advice what is causing this error?

Comment: you have a Windows 7 PC with more than 24GB RAM?

Answer (score 0):

The problem revolves around disk space, pagefiles and memory.

Shut machine down.

Reduce machine memory to the minimum, say 1 or 2 GB, and then restart and allow to boot normally.

Once awake, increase C:\ space to allow for the additional memory or split the pagefile(s) and set them to **"fixed"** at 2048 MB on C: and 24576 MB on another drive.

Reboot the machine.

Once awake, make sure everything is all OK. Shutdown, increase the memory back to 24 GB and restart.

Should all be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error. But in my case I assigned 512M RAM to virtual machine (for Windows 7, 64 bit). The solution was to increase the RAM to 1024.

Comment: Please provide more information as this is a very spare answer and likely not going to fix it as the OP indicated they have 24GB of RAM assigned to the VM.